# Unmarshaling JSON not printing values in stuct

Tags: json, go, slack-api

I am trying to get list of reminders from slack by calling its api. I need to extract the time stamp and user id from the response. But I am not able to get values copied to struct while unmarshaling the JSON.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

type ReadingHttpResponse struct {
    ID         string    `json:"id"`
    Creator    string    `json:"creator"`
    User       string    `json:"user"`
    Text       string    `json:"text"`
    Recurring  bool      `json:"recurring"`
    Time       time.Time `json:"time"`
    CompleteTS int       `json:"complete_ts"`
}

func main() {

url := "https://slack.com/api/reminders.list"
    var bearer = "Bearer " + "My Bearer token"
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    req.Header.Add("Authorization", bearer)
    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error on response.\n[ERRO] -", err)
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    var m ReadingHttpResponse

    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &m)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

   fmt.Printf("%#v\r\n", m)

}
```

### json in response from api is

> "ok":true,"reminders":[{"id":"bacsasdad","creator":"asdasdww","user":"asdasdad","text":"Hello this is for testing purpose only","recurring":false,"time":1578470823,"complete_ts":0}]}

### But the Unmarshaled data has no values

main.ReadingHttpResponse{ID:"", Creator:"", User:"", Text:"", Recurring:false, Time:time.Time{wall:0x0, ext:0, loc:(*time.Location)(nil)}, CompleteTS:0}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your struct doesn’t correspond to the JSON response, it should be like:

```golang
type ReadingHttpResponse struct {
    Ok        bool `json:"ok"`
    Reminders []Reminder `json:"reminders"`
}

type Reminder struct {
        ID         string `json:"id"`
        Creator    string `json:"creator"`
        User       string `json:"user"`
        Text       string `json:"text"`
        Recurring  bool   `json:"recurring"`
        Time       int    `json:"time"`
        CompleteTs int    `json:"complete_ts"`
}
```

Comment: @NitinChauhan You can use [this tool](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/) to convert your JSON to Go structs, then you always have a correct struct